# I am trying to create a signin page but after sign in a file with 0 kb is getting downloaded and getting CSRF verification failed

Tags: python, django

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Signup Page</title>
   {% load static %}

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'login/signuppage.css' %}">
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="login">
   <div class ="form">
    <h3>Sign in</h3>
    <form class="registration-form" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <p>{{ field.label_tag }}
                {{ field }}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
             </p>
        {% endfor %}
        <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email ID"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>-->
        <button>Sign in</button>
        <p><a href ="#">Login</a></p>

    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Sign in page views
views.py:

```
  def SignupPage(request):
     form = UserSigninForm()

     if request.method=='POST':
     form=UserSigninForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        user=form.save()
        auth_login(request, user)
        return redirect('/home/')
     else:
        form = UserSigninForm()
  context = {'form': form}
  return render(request,'login/signuppage.html',context)
```

signin page forms forms.py:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 from django import forms
 from django.forms import ModelForm

 class UserSigninForm(UserCreationForm):
 class Meta:
    model = User
    fields=['username','email','password1','password2']
```

I am trying to create a signin page but after sign in a file with 0 kb is getting downloaded and getting CSRF verification failed. Request aborted as an error. I am trying not to exempt csrf token in code. What needs to be done here to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problme:

```
 <button>Sign in</button>
```

Do it:

```
 <button type="submit" >Sign in</button>
```